# How to add help text inside the search bar

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, html

I want to display help text on click of lightning input field without display info icon. Let me know if any code is there.

Comment: Did you tried using the title attribute?

Comment: Yes with title now it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding as an answer.

You can use the `title` attribute or `placeholder` to display the help text.